# A few problems about symmetric matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

I got a few problems about symmetric matrices (from Titu's Linear Algebra book) and seem like unable to solve them.

1. Find all symmetric matrices $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A + A^3 + A^5 = 3I_n?$

The answer seems to be $A=I_n$, I managed to show that $(A-I)(A^4+A^3+2A^2+2A+I)=O_n$, but this implies nothing. I knew I haven't use the hypothesis that $A$ is symmetric.

2. Find all matrices $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $A^TAA = I_n$. (Hint: Start by proving that such a matrix $A$ is symmetric.)

I tried to multiply both sides with $A$ (either to the left and to the right) then take the transpose of both side but still can not show that $A$ is symmetric. Afterward I skip that part and assume $A$ is symmetric, but also can not find $A$, again, the answer seems to be $A=I_n$.

Any helps is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use the spectral theorem? Also, if $A^TA^2=I_n$ then we see $A^{-1}=A^TA$. Now transposing both sides of $A^TA^2=I_n$ gives $(A^T)^2A=I_n$ which implies $(A^T)^{-1}=A^TA$. Hence $A^{-1}=(A^T)^{-1}$ and so $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: If you can use the spectral theorem, you can express $A$ as $QDQ^T$ where $Q$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal. Equation $(1)$ becomes $$D+D^3+D^5=3I_n$$ while Equation $(2)$ becomes $$D^3=I_n$$which you can solve much more easily.

Comment: sorry I can't see what is the Equation (2)  you are talking about, can you explain a bit please? Thanks!

Comment: Equation (2) is $A^TA^2=I_n$

Comment: I mean you know this is two separate problems right, I thought you were only solving the first one. So, how do we answer for the first problems? since equation $D+D^3+D^5=3I_n$ has so many solution and moreover, it is not $A$.

Comment: My first comment refers to your second problem, while the strategy I presented in my second comment refers to both problems. If you can solve these equations for a diagonal matrix $D$ then you can find out what $A$ is by pre and post multiplying by $Q$ and $Q^T$ respectively.

Comment: To find out what the possible candidates for $D$ for problem #1, you should consider the real solutions to the polynomial equation $x+x^3+x^5=3$. To find the possible $D$ matrices in problem #2, consider the real solutions to $x^3=1$.

Comment: I understood now, thanks for your patience and enthusiasm.